# Not able to download log files using following API

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We are not able to download log files. Once run below command, it is getting unable to parse object filter.

curl -X GET -u : -g https://api.service.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Event_Log/getAllObjects.json

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to retrieve the Event Logs through SoftLayer's private network, I used the same request:

```
curl -X GET -u $user:$apiKey -g https://api.service.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Event_Log/getAllObjects.json
```

According to the exception, it seems that you are sending something else in the request.

Are you able to make others api calls? can you try again please? Did you have success before with this request?

Also, can you try with the public endpoint: https://api.softlayer.com instead of https://api.service.softlayer.com